# Reactjs: How to make all row checkbox check true when material table is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using react material table in my project and i want to make selection by default checked. How to achieve that??

```
function BasicSelection() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Basic Selection Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'a', surname: 'b', birthYear: c, birthCity: d },
        { name: 'e', surname: 'f', birthYear: g, birthCity: h },
      ]}        
      options={{
        selection: true
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the checked status in the selection props.

```
options={{
    selection: true,
    selectionProps: rowData => ({
      checked: true,
    })
 }}
```

Here it keeps the rows checked all the time. You can update the function to have a condition based on the selection change event.

Comment: but then its always true... could not deselect then

Comment: You can keep track of the items that need to be checked in an array. Update the array when on click event on check boxes. In the selectedProps, check for the condition whether the rowData presents in the array and based on that assign true or false to checked value.